# How to Split logstash Config file

Tags: logstash

In my scenario, two teams are using and updating logstash config file. I thought of splitting the config file into two so two teams can do changes independently. Just read the logstash doc and didn't find a way to that, any idea?

Comment: from documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html  You can see that it's possible to run logstash with custom config: `logstash -f path/to/custom-config.yml`  so every team will have own config file and run logstash separately

Answer (score 0):

You can follow num8er advice and run Logstash using specific config file or if you have Logtash version 6.0+ then you can use `multiple pipelines` feature and run both config files at the same time or run just one by commenting another in the pipelines config file. To do so you have to create pipelines config file `pipelines.yml` in the `path.settings` folder:

```
- pipeline.id: team1-pipeline
  path.config: "/etc/path/to/team1/config/file"
  pipeline.workers: 1
- pipeline.id: team2-pipeline
  path.config: "/etc/path/to/team2/config/file"
  pipeline.workers: 1
```

Next time just rune Logstash without specifing config files path with `-e` or `-f` and Logstash will run pipelines based on `pipelines.yml` file.